# Link not displaying from db

Tags: php, avatar

I have a login script, and a table with fields, the one required here is 'avatar'( varchar(255) & defaul entry is an image link)

Code for viewing the profile:

```
<div align="center"><img src="<?php echo $_GET['avatar']; ?>" width="250" height="250" /></div>
```

Code for session:

```
function set_session($username, $password) {

    $query = $this->query("SELECT * FROM ".DBTBLE." WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");

    ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", Session_Lifetime); 
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['first_name']    = $query['result']['first_name'];
    $_SESSION['last_name']     = $query['result']['last_name'];
    $_SESSION['email_address'] = $query['result']['email_address'];
    $_SESSION['username']      = $query['result']['username'];
    $_SESSION['info']          = $query['result']['info'];
    $_SESSION['user_level']    = $query['result']['user_level'];
    $_SESSION['password']      = $query['result']['password'];
    $_SESSION['avatar']        = $query['result']['avatar'];

}
```

There was no feature for adding an avatar, so I added the show `<div>` function in the form, created a column in the database named avatar, and added `$_SESSION['avatar'] = $query['result']['avatar']` but the default image isn't displaying, where did I go wrong? Except from avatar, rest all is been displayed.

Comment: avoid saving password in sessison..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
src="<?php echo $_GET['avatar']; ?>"
```

should be:

```
src="<?php echo $_SESSION['avatar']; ?>"
```

Comment: Use the ternary operator for check if the session is set

Comment: @Barmar, yes it worked, it was dumb mistake, please ignore my lack of knowledge, and thank you.